# Update on Cascade Oracle com chave primária composta

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, oracle

```
create or replace TRIGGER cascade_update

    AFTER UPDATE OF project_name ON PROJECT
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN

      UPDATE VEHICLE
       SET project_name = :new.project_name
       WHERE project_name = :old.project_name;

       UPDATE VELOCITY_LIMIT
       SET project_name = :new.project_name
       WHERE project_name = :old.project_name;

       UPDATE ENERGY
       SET project_name = :new.project_name
       WHERE project_name = :old.project_name;

       UPDATE GEAR
       SET project_name = :new.project_name
       WHERE project_name = :old.project_name;

       UPDATE THROTTLE
       SET project_name = :new.project_name
       WHERE project_name = :old.project_name;

       UPDATE REGIME
       SET project_name = :new.project_name
       WHERE project_name = :old.project_name;

       UPDATE NETWORK
       SET project_name = :new.project_name
       WHERE project_name = :old.project_name;

       UPDATE ROAD
       SET project_name = :new.project_name
       WHERE project_name = :old.project_name;

       UPDATE TOLL
       SET project_name = :new.project_name
       WHERE project_name = :old.project_name;

       UPDATE SECTION
       SET project_name = :new.project_name
       WHERE project_name = :old.project_name;

       UPDATE LOCAL
       SET project_name = :new.project_name
       WHERE project_name = :old.project_name;

    END;
```

.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE UPDATE_Project(old_name Project.project_name%type, project_name2 Project.project_name%type, project_description2  Project.project_description%type)
    IS

    BEGIN
    UPDATE PROJECT
    SET project_name = project_name2,
    project_description = project_description2
    WHERE project_name = old_name;

    END;
```

Preciso fazer update ao campo `project_name` que está em todas as tabelas, mas quando executo o procedure que criei apresenta estes erros.
Gostava de saber a melhor solução para atualizar todos os campos.

SEVERE: ORA-02292: restrição de integridade (FKROAD185752) violada - encontrado registo filho

ORA-06512: na "CASCADE_UPDATE", linha 27

ORA-04088: erro durante a execução do trigger 'CASCADE_UPDATE'

ORA-06512: na "UPDATE_PROJECT", linha 5

ORA-06512: na linha 1

Comment: 1º faça SELECT *
FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'FKROAD185752' 2º Na definição da tabela PROJECT existe provavelmente uma condição cascade ( http://javaaberto.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/usando-cascade-no-banco-de-dados.html )

Comment: O resultado da query foi este https://image.prntscr.com/image/8256CX6CRWuN-eBji5dgkQ.png.
E não consigo meter a condição `ON UPDATE ON DELETE` no Oracle, dá-me sempre erro

Comment: Na descrição da tabela ROAD o que diz esta constraint ?

Comment: A descrição de todas as Constraints da tabela `Road` estão aqui
https://image.prntscr.com/image/O36IzeAaQwqzCZ9bJ7yHBA.png      - 
https://image.prntscr.com/image/73qNDTc1ScegaPn3qkJsQQ.png

Comment: Publica se possível a descrição total das tabelas , procure nas tabelas envolvidas um cascade que possa estar gerando o erro , lembro todavia que as tabelas estivessem normalizadas o problema não ocorreria pois project_name deveria ser atributo apenas de PROJECT

Comment: mas eu tenho project_name nas tabelas todas porque `project_name` faz parte de uma chave primária composta, logo quando outra tabela precisa ser associada recebe o campo `project_name` por default

Comment: Já está a funcionar.
Optei por criar outro campo paraser a chave primária.